# HTMl Table's border not showing on Php PDF

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

Why do the borders of my tables not appear when I print my pdf to the screen?

I'm using the mPDF library.

I create the tables in html and for some reason it is not showing.

I already tried using inline CSS but it didn't work, for me.

```
<?php
    require_once 'MPDF57\MPDF57\mpdf.php';

    class TablePDF {
        public function printPDF() {
            $mpdf = new mPDF();
            $border = 2 ;
            $mpdf->SetHeader("Tabela");
            $mpdf->SetFooter("Tabela");
            $htmlpdf= "
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <link type='text/css' rel=' rel='heet' href=' href='tstrap.min.css'>
                        <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/estilo.css'>
                        <style type='.text/css.'>
                            <title>Table</title>
                        </style>
                        .td{
                            style='border: 1px solid';
                          }
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <table class='tabela' border=".$border." style='border:10px solid;'>
                            <tr style='border:10px solid black'>
                                <th width='150' style='border:10px solid black; '>GE</th>
                                <td width='200' style='border:10px solid black; '>0</td>
                                <td width='200' style='border:10px solid black; '><strong>Nome Curto</strong></td>
                                <td width='200' style='border:10px solid black;  '>0</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        <table class='tabela' border=".$border." style='border:10px solid black'>
                            <tr>
                                <th width='150'>Valor</th>
                                <td width='200'>0</td>
                                <td width='200'><strong>FG</strong></td>
                                <td width='200'>0</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        <table class='tabela' border=".$border." style='border:10px solid black'>
                            <tr>
                                <th width='150'> Jugular </th>
                                <td width='117'>0</td>
                                <td width='117'>0</td>
                                <td width='117'>0</td>
                                <td width='118'>0</td>
                                <td width='119'>0</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        <table class='tabela' border=".$border." style='border:10px solid black'>
                            <tr>
                                <th width='150'>EXP3D</th>
                                <td width='200'>0</td>
                                <td width='200'>0</td>
                                <td width='200'>0</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        <table class='tabela' border=".$border." style='border:10px solid black'>
                            <tr>
                                <th width='150'>EXP28D</th>
                                <td width='200'>0</td>
                                <td width='200'>0</td>
                                <td width='200'>0</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        <table class='tabela' border=".$border." style='border:10px solid black'>
                            <tr>
                                <th width='150'>Carotida</th>
                                <td width='303'>0</td>
                                <td width='303'>0</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </body>
                </html>";
            $mpdf -> useOnlyCoreFonts = true;
            $mpdf->WriteHTML($htmlpdf);
            $mpdf->Output();
        }
    }
?>
```

Then I use this to use this function to print the pdf:

```
<?php
    require_once 'TablePDF.php';
    $var = new TablePDF();
    $var->printPDF();
?>
```

EDIT: the problem has been solved, i just started deleting the table class in the TABLE tag line because for some reason it wastn recognizing it as a class.

thanks alot folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
td {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

You don't have to create style every time that you need to use a td in your page, you only call the style.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid CSS. Am I missing something?

Comment: As far as I know, using `style:` inside a style declaration is illegal.